# collectd aggregation plugin not working?

Tags: collectd

Can't for the life of me get the aggregation plugin to produce anything.  I have

```
LoadPlugin aggregation
```

...uncommented.  And I have this block:

```
<Plugin "aggregation">
     <Aggregation>
         Plugin "cpu"
         Type "cpu"

         GroupBy "Host"  
         GroupBy "TypeInstance"

         CalculateSum true
         CalculateAverage true
     </Aggregation>
 </Plugin>
```

...which is just pulled from the wiki.  The cpu plugin specification is:

```
<Plugin cpu>
    ReportByCpu true
    ReportByState false
    ValuesPercentage true
</Plugin>
```

It reports the cpu values fine, but not the aggregate.  I've tried a bunch of aggregation specifications and none work.  This is on Ubuntu 16.04 (I think), default installation of collectd.

Answer (score 1):

Make the type in aggregation plugin as percent instead of cpu as you have mentioned ValuesPercentage as true in Plugin cpu.

```
<Plugin "aggregation">
     <Aggregation>
         Plugin "cpu"
         Type "percent"

         GroupBy "Host"  
         GroupBy "TypeInstance"

         CalculateSum true
         CalculateAverage true
     </Aggregation>
 </Plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like "ReportByState" has to be true and "ValuesPercentage" has to be false.  For no apparent reason.  And not documented anywhere. :-/